# Oracle SQL: Optimizer doesn't choose the optimal way?

Tags: oracle, optimization

Each individual query take less than 10 seconds to perform.

But when I join these queries together, by using the `IN` keyword and a list, the optimizer creates an odd explain plan and the query takes ages (think hours).

I have included the queries below.
Do I have to force some kind of indexing?

Query 1:

```
select row_number() over (partition by  t1.COLUMN_1, t1.COLUMN_2, t1.COLUMN_3 order by t1.RSLT_DT desc) rn, 
      t1.COLUMN_1,
      t1.RSLT_DT,
      t1.COLUMN_2,
      t1.COLUMN_3,
      t1.MY_SCORE
      from MY_DB.MY_TABLE t1
      where t1.COLUMN_3 in ('FACT_1','FACT_0') 
      and t1.COLUMN_1 
      in ('33162046') 
      and MY_SCORE > 0;

Plan hash value: 3324896092

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                | 70545 |  4202K|       |  7545K (40)| 37:43:34 |       |       |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT                        |                | 70545 |  4202K|  5312K|  7545K (40)| 37:43:34 |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION RANGE ALL               |                | 70545 |  4202K|       |  7544K (40)| 37:43:26 |     1 |1048575|
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| MY_TABLE     | 70545 |  4202K|       |  7544K (40)| 37:43:26 |     1 |1048575|
|   4 |     BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS     |                |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   5 |      BITMAP AND                     |                |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   6 |       BITMAP OR                     |                |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|*  7 |        BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE    | MY_TABLE_X27 |       |       |       |            |          |     1 |1048575|
|*  8 |        BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE    | MY_TABLE_X27 |       |       |       |            |          |     1 |1048575|
|   9 |       BITMAP MERGE                  |                |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|* 10 |        BITMAP INDEX RANGE SCAN      | MY_TABLE_X21 |       |       |       |            |          |     1 |1048575|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("MY_SCORE">0)
   7 - access("T1"."COLUMN_3"='FACT_0')
   8 - access("T1"."COLUMN_3"='FACT_1')
  10 - access("T1"."COLUMN_1"=33162046)
       filter("T1"."COLUMN_1"=33162046)
```

Query 2:

```
select row_number() over (partition by  t1.COLUMN_1, t1.COLUMN_2, t1.COLUMN_3 order by t1.RSLT_DT desc) rn, 
          t1.COLUMN_1,
          t1.RSLT_DT,
          t1.COLUMN_2,
          t1.COLUMN_3,
          t1.MY_SCORE
          from MY_DB.MY_TABLE t1
          where t1.COLUMN_3 in ('FACT_1','FACT_0') 
          and t1.COLUMN_1 
          in ('33162047')
          and MY_SCORE > 0;


Plan hash value: 3324896092

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                | 70545 |  4202K|       |  7545K (40)| 37:43:34 |       |       |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT                        |                | 70545 |  4202K|  5312K|  7545K (40)| 37:43:34 |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION RANGE ALL               |                | 70545 |  4202K|       |  7544K (40)| 37:43:26 |     1 |1048575|
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| MY_TABLE     | 70545 |  4202K|       |  7544K (40)| 37:43:26 |     1 |1048575|
|   4 |     BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS     |                |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   5 |      BITMAP AND                     |                |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   6 |       BITMAP OR                     |                |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|*  7 |        BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE    | MY_TABLE_X27 |       |       |       |            |          |     1 |1048575|
|*  8 |        BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE    | MY_TABLE_X27 |       |       |       |            |          |     1 |1048575|
|   9 |       BITMAP MERGE                  |                |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|* 10 |        BITMAP INDEX RANGE SCAN      | MY_TABLE_X21 |       |       |       |            |          |     1 |1048575|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("MY_SCORE">0)
   7 - access("T1"."COLUMN_3"='FACT_0')
   8 - access("T1"."COLUMN_3"='FACT_1')
  10 - access("T1"."COLUMN_1"=33162047)
       filter("T1"."COLUMN_1"=33162047)
```

Joined Query:

```
select row_number() over (partition by  t1.COLUMN_1, t1.COLUMN_2, t1.COLUMN_3 order by t1.RSLT_DT desc) rn, 
      t1.COLUMN_1,
      t1.RSLT_DT,
      t1.COLUMN_2,
      t1.COLUMN_3,
      t1.MY_SCORE
      from MY_DB.MY_TABLE t1
      where t1.COLUMN_3 in ('FACT_1','FACT_0') 
      and t1.COLUMN_1 
      in ('33162046','33162047') 
      and MY_SCORE > 0;

Plan hash value: 2547923189

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                | 70545 |  4202K|       |    11M  (1)| 59:28:46 |       |       |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT                         |                | 70545 |  4202K|  5312K|    11M  (1)| 59:28:46 |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION RANGE ALL                |                | 70545 |  4202K|       |    11M  (1)| 59:28:38 |     1 |1048575|
|   3 |    INLIST ITERATOR                   |                |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| MY_TABLE     | 70545 |  4202K|       |    11M  (1)| 59:28:38 |     1 |1048575|
|   5 |      BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS     |                |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|*  6 |       BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE      | MY_TABLE_X27 |       |       |       |            |          |     1 |1048575|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - filter(("T1"."COLUMN_1"=33162046 OR "T1"."COLUMN_1"=33162047) AND "MY_SCORE">0)
   6 - access("T1"."COLUMN_3"='FACT_0' OR "T1"."COLUMN_3"='FACT_1')
```

Comment: Do you have any dynamic sampling going on? I'd certainly try it myself as the optimiser might be finding it difficult to get an accurate estimate of the expected row count. Are the estimated row counts accurate at all?

Comment: @DavidAldridge I'm not sure - I think I'd need to ask the DBA, which may take a while, unless there is a way to find out?
My output is really small, 10s of rows, but I think the source data is huge (millions of rows)

Comment: Well it seems to have over a million partitions, so  I'd hope it has at least a billion or so rows. The execution plan ought to be telling you whether dynamic sampling is applied or not.

Comment: I don't see any dynamic sampling in the execution plan. How to force it?

Comment: Add an appropriate optimiser hint

Comment: what level should I set it at? not sure how to choose between 1 and 10

Comment: Read the docs to see what the values mean, but test low values first (2, 3, 4) to see if they can get you a different execution plan that involves the index on COLUMN_1. If not, look at index hints to see what is available that can get that index in use, preferably in combination with the index on COLUMN_3

Comment: May be you could try a `UNION ALL` of the two queries?

Comment: @mustaccio, I does make sense, but basically I'm going through simple examples as I'd like to extend that query to maybe 400 values

Comment: If that's the case, are you sure the index on `COLUMN_1` should be a bitmap?

Comment: @mustaccio, great point! I'll contact the table owner